# Jquery hover, Как сделать чтобы работало только на один из блоков?

Tags: jquery, hover

```js
 $('.block-content a').hover(function() {
   $('.block-name span:nth-of-type(2)').css('width', '100%');
 }, function() {
   $('.block-name span:nth-of-type(2)').css('width', '60%');
 });
```

```html
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block1.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block2.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block3.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block4.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block5.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Есть 5 блоков, при наведении на ссылку в одном из них на всех других span становиться шириной 100%, как сделать, чтобы функцию выполнялась только в том блоке, в котором находиться ссылка?

Comment: Покажите отрывок html с ссылками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С ссылки обращаетесь к ближайшему общему родителю, а от туда к самому `span`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.block-content a').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.block-content').find('.block-name span:nth-of-type(2)').css('width', '100%');
  }, function() {
    $(this).closest('.block-content').find('.block-name span:nth-of-type(2)').css('width', '60%');
  });
});
```

```css
.block-name span {display:block; width: 60%; height: 15px; margin: 5px 0; background-color:black;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block1.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block2.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block3.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block4.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-name">
    <img src="/img/block5.png">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Comment: лучше `closest`

Comment: Благодарю, в дальнейшем буду знать, как решать подобные задачи!

Comment: @Voo, изменил под ваш *html*